# Odd behaviour in phone gap barcode scanner plugin. For iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, barcode

I seem to have run into an interesting bug

In creating a iOS application using apache Cordova 2.2 and the latest barcode scanner plugin from the GitHub repo we are able to have the app run in both portrait and landscape and the barcode overlay and camera show up properly.

The issue comes in when trying to read a barcode in landscape mode. Although the overlay (red line, green box) rotate according to orientation, the read capture part seems to stay in portrait.

What I mean is in landscape mode you have to turn the physical object 90 degrees sudo portrait mode?

Has anyone encountered this?